# How to edit/overwrite the layout of a widget in javascript?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, widget

I have a Wordpress page and I have added a Sidebar widget for an air quality measurement device. The script generated by the device is written looks like this:

```
<div name="airvisual_widget" key="somecodehere"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.airvisual.com/scripts/widget_v2.0.js"></script>
```

And this generates a widget that looks like this:

[image]

So the layout is very weird and gets off limits and there are not really many layout options on the website that generates that widget code. Is it possible to overwrite or edit the standard layout inside this javascript code? And how can one do that?

Comment: You should be able to control the layout using CSS. Inspect the widget and find the CSS which you can override

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. How can I inspect the widget?

Comment: In chrome, right click on widget, and click inspect. Before writing your css, you can try directly in chrome developer toolbar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did take a look at the widget code. And was able to change the layout using CSS.

You can add CSS for these classes and use `!important` to override existing properties of the widget

[image: Widget]

Once you know the dom structure and CSS selectors, you can add custom css targetting these selectors. For example, in the above screenshot, if you want to change the height of div with class `bodyAirvisualWidget`, you can add custom CSS like

```css
.bodyAirvisualWidget {
    height: 200px;
}
```

You can choose to add `!important` to force your css. However you need to be careful as same css selector may be targetting multiple element. In that case you may want to make your css selector more specific like `div.className > div.anotherClass > .bodyAirvisualWidget` to avoid unintended side effects

If it was a simple html page, you can add CSS directly in a `<style>` tag or in a CSS file and include css file into your page.

In case of Wordpress, you can add custom CSS via Wordpress CSS editor (My Site → Design → Customize → Additional CSS)

Comment: Thanks again. I have managed to get into that code using "Inspect", but I can't really change the code from Chrome. Do I need to write those lines inside the Widget box in Wordpress?

Comment: Chrome developer toolbar will only give you information about what to change. You can use Wordpress CSS editor (My Site → Design → Customize → Additional CSS) to add the custom CSS

Comment: Works! Thank you. Can you please add a bit more details to your answer so I can choose it to to be the right one?

Comment: Perfect! I hope this will help some others too.